# Difference between String, FormattableString, IFormattable

Tags: c#, string, formattable, iformattable, formattablestring

`FormattableString` has been Introduced in C# 6.0. As we can use same string formatting using `string` object why is there need of using `FormattableString` or `IFormattable`. Whats difference between three?

My Code

```
        var name = "Pravin";
        var s = $"Hello, {name}";
        System.IFormattable s1 = $"Hello, {name}";
        System.FormattableString s2 = $"Hello, {name}";
```

Above all there produces same result. i.e `'Hello Pravin'.`

Can I get more elaborated answer on this if anyone has deep knowledge on same.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`FormattableString` is a new type in .NET 4.6, and the compiler will only use it if you *try* to use it. In other words, the type of an interpolated string literal is normally `string` - built with `string.Format` - but can be `FormattableString` (via `FormattableStringFactory`) if you ask for it.

A `FormattableString` consists of the format string which would be passed to `string.Format` (e.g. `"Hello, {0}"`) and the arguments that would be passed in order to format it. Crucially, this information is captured *before* formatting.

This allows you to adjust the formatting appropriately - most commonly to perform it in the invariant culture, often with the [`Invariant` static method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring.invariant(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you assign an interpolated string literal to an `IFormattable` variable, that will use `FormattableString` too. The [`IFormattable.ToString(string, CultureInfo)` implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906196(v=vs.110).aspx) ignores the first argument in this case, which is presumably why it uses explicit interface implementation.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using static System.FormattableString;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var uk = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = uk;
        var germany = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
        string now = $"Default: it is now {DateTime.UtcNow}";
        Console.WriteLine(now); // UK format
        IFormattable x = $"Specific: It is now {DateTime.UtcNow}";
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("ignored", germany));
        FormattableString y = $"FormattableString: It is now {DateTime.UtcNow}";
        Console.WriteLine(FormattableString.Invariant(y));
        // Via using static
        Console.WriteLine(Invariant($"It is now {DateTime.UtcNow}")); 
    }
}
```

Sample results:

```
Default: it is now 16/02/2016 07:16:21
Specific: It is now 16.02.2016 07:16:21
FormattableString: It is now 02/16/2016 07:16:21
It is now 02/16/2016 07:16:21
```

Comment: Since `string` does not implement `IFormattable`, using `FormattableString` is only choice, when you cast interpolated string to `IFormattable`.

Comment: @PetSerAI: You're absolutely right. Not sure what I was thinking. Will edit. When I get to the office...

Comment: @JonSkeet Just looking at a line of code from the Microsoft open XML SDK:
`RawOuterXml = Invariant($"<!--{xmlReader.Value}-->");`
Where RawOuterXml and xmlReader.Value are both strings. Will the Invariant call do anything to a variable that is already a string?

Comment: @axeman: I suspect not, no - but it may be one of those situations where it's easier to make multiple calls use `Invariant` than to reason about each one individually.

Answer (score 8):

As an aside, https://www.meziantou.net/interpolated-strings-advanced-usages.htm covers some examples of what FormattableString allows you to do (e.g. auto-parameterising SQL statements)

e.g.

```cs
void ExecuteNonQuery(DbConnection connection, FormattableString formattableString)
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Replace values by @p0, @p1, @p2, ....
        var args = Enumerable.Range(0, formattableString.ArgumentCount).Select(i => (object)("@p" + i)).ToArray();

        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = string.Format(formattableString.Format, args);

        // Create parameters
        for (var i = 0; i < formattableString.ArgumentCount; i++)
        {
            var arg = formattableString.GetArgument(i);
            var p = command.CreateParameter();
            p.ParameterName = "@p" + i;
            p.Value = arg;
            command.Parameters.Add(p);
        }

        // Execute the command
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    ExecuteNonQuery(sqlConnection, $@"UPDATE Customers SET Name = {"Meziantou"} WHERE Id = {1}");
}
```