# How to interpolate string from a const value?

Tags: c#

I have a string constant:

```
const string VERSION = "#version {ver}";
```

Later on, once configurations are loaded, is it possible to interpolate the constant?

```
public string VerAttrib { get; private set; }

public void SetVersion(string ver) {
   // pseudo code
   VerAttrib = $VERSION;
}
```

Comment: You can't. String interpolation is just sugar around the compiler doing a `string.Format` , `string.Concat`/etc. operations.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425899/difference-between-string-formattablestring-iformattable. Btw.  `"#version {ver}"` isn't an interpolated string, you meant `$"#version {ver}"` maybe?

Comment: Maybe just manual string.replace or regexp in basic cases. Or some template engine like Jinja or someting may be an option for more complex cases.

Comment: If the constant is `"#version {0}"` then you can just use it in any call to `string.Format` or anything else that formats a string.  (e.g. `Console.Write`, etc.)

Comment: It's not just syntactic sugar. A string interpolation expression is a [FormattableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=net-8.0a), not a string.

Comment: In any case, you can't do what you want, even if you store the FormattableString to a `static readonly` field. You're trying to use method parameters in a static context. You wouldn't be able to use even an instance field or property. You can pass a `FormattableString` as the first argument of `String.Format` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` though

Comment: In .NET 8 you can use the [CompositeFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.compositeformat?view=net-8.0) to store a *parsed* version of a format string, and pass that to new overloads of String.Format

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```cs
const string VERSION = "#version {0}"; // Note: `ver` was replaced by an index

VerAttrib = String.Format(VERSION, ver);
```